# Javascript: how to print out object and array argument

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a Javascript issue; I'm wondering if it's possible to print out both an object followed by an argument as an array? Here is what I've done so far:

```
var index;
var items = ('a', ['b', 'c']);

for (index = 0; index < items.length; ++index) {
    demoP.innerHTML = demoP.innerHTML + items[index] + "<br>"; 
}
```

Which prints out:
b
c

However, I want to print out:
a
b
c

Any suggestions would be most welcome!

Comment: What is numbers ? This is not an object or an array

Comment: numbers isn't an obj or an array.

Comment: `numbers` is indeed an array. However, using the comma is executing two statements, assigning only the array to the variable. Obviously not what OP wants but important to clarify why they get the first output

Comment: for (index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) - What will happen when you increment the "index++" in your for loop?

Comment: but not one that holds 3,4,10. its being converted to the array ['4','10']

Comment: correct this code `('3', ['4', '10'])`. It's unclear

Comment: change numbers to `var numbers = ['3','4', '10'];`. Though why it's in the format in the first place isn't clear

Comment: change it to [3, 4, 10] and why not use `numbers.join('<br/>')` instead of the loop.

Comment: That's an incorrect array, numbers will only hold the inner array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell

```
var numbers = ('3', ['4', '10']);
```

uses the comma operator, which first evaluates '3', then ['4', '10'] and returns the last as result. The parentheses seem to have no further effect here.

So it seems to be equivalent to

```
var numbers = ['4', '10'];
```

Answer (score 2):

### Description

`items` was defined incorrectly and thereby didn't contain `'a'`.

**Demo**

```js
var items = ('a', ['b', 'c']);
console.log(items);

//which is being run like this...but since we are logging after it is done we don't see `a` at all
var items = (console.log('a'), console.log(['b', 'c']))
```

*Note: an object is defined with `{` and `}` not `(` and `)`, it also requires there to be a `key: value` for each item*

### The change

```js
var items = ['a', ['b', 'c']];
console.log(items);
```

### The fix

**Method 1**

```js
var numbers = ['a', ['b', 'c']];
var demoP = document.getElementById('demoP');

demoP.innerHTML = [].concat.apply([], numbers).join('<BR/>');
```

```html
<div id="demoP"></div>
```

**Method 2**

```js
var index;
var numbers = ['a', ['b', 'c']];
var demoP = document.getElementById('demoP');
var result = '';

iterateItems(numbers);

demoP.innerHTML = result;

function iterateItems(arr) {
  for (var index = 0, length = arr.length; index < length; ++index) {
    if( Object.prototype.toString.call( arr[index] ) === '[object Array]' ) {
      iterateItems(arr[index]);
    } else {
      result += arr[index] + "<br>"; 
    }
  } 
}
```

```html
<div id="demoP"></div>
```

Comment: Cheers! So it wouldn't be possible to declare items as ('a', ['b', 'c'])?

Comment: @leonOsmania that is two declarations because of the comma, you could use `{'a':'a', 'b': ['b','c']}` as this is an object declaration or you could also use the array notation `['a', ['b', 'c']]` but no `('a', ['b', 'c'])` is actually running to declarations setting the variable to 'a' then to `['b', 'c']`

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the number value as the following array element?

**var numbers = ['3', ['4', '10']];**

Hope thsi will solve your question:

```
<div id="demoP"></div>
<br><br>
<script>
var index;
var numbers = ['3', ['4', '10']];

for (index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) {
    demoP.innerHTML = demoP.innerHTML + numbers[index] + "<br>"; 
}
</script>
</p>
```

**Result :**
[image]

Reference of Online code executed: http://js.do/code/139843

Comment: Thank you! However, I'm curious as to whether it would be possible to print out each item from ('3', ['4', '10']) rather than enclosing one array inside another?

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), and a wrong way of declaring an array. This line

```
var numbers = ('3', ['4', '10']);
```

assigns 3 to numbers, then evaluates to the right and immediately after overrides numbers again and assigns the array `['4', '10']` to your variable.

So this will log `['4', '10']`:

```js
var numbers = ('3', ['4', '10']);
console.log(numbers);
```

As your intention is to print 3,4,10 - a simple array will do that:

```js
var index;
var items = ['3', '4', '10'];

for (index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
    demoP.innerHTML = demoP.innerHTML + items[index] + "<br>"; 
}
```

```html
<div id="demoP"></div>
```